# Sniffer realized on python does not capture anything?

Tags: python, sockets, packet-sniffers, sniffing, kali-linux

I copied from a book this small code that should capture the traffic (ip headers) accross all my WLAN. Howewhere i cannot capture anything when lauching; the code blocks when "socket.recv(..)". I can only see results if the variable "host" is setted as "localhost" and from another terminal i ping myself (cmd -> "ping localhost"). I have even a question... this code should run both on linux and windows (for example protocol IPPROTO_IP is not supported on linux (I got an error), so it sets ICMP); why the promiscuos mode in handles only if the machine is running windows? Thank you all, hope someone can help me

```
import socket
import os 
import struct
from ctypes import *

host = "localhost"

class IP(Structure):
    
    _fields_ = [
        ("ihl", c_ubyte, 4),
        ("version", c_ubyte, 4),
        ("tos", c_ubyte),
        ("len", c_ushort),
        ("id", c_ushort),
        ("offset", c_ushort),
        ("ttl", c_ubyte),
        ("protocol_num", c_ubyte),
        ("sum", c_ushort),
        ("src", c_uint),
        ("dst", c_uint),
    ]
    
    def __new__(self, socket_buffer=None):
        return self.from_buffer_copy(socket_buffer)
    
    def __init__(self, socket_buffer=None):
        self.protocol_map = {1 : "ICMP", 6 : "TCP", 17 : "UDP"}
        self.src_address = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("<L", self.src))
        self.dst_address = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("<L", self.dst))
        try:
            self.protocol = self.protocol_map[self.protocol_num]
        except:
            self.protocol = str(self.protocol_num)
        
if os.name == "nt":
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_IP
else:
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_ICMP 
    
sniffer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket_protocol)
sniffer.bind((host, 0))
print("[*] Starting...")

sniffer.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

if os.name == "nt":
    sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

try:
    while True:
        raw_buffer = sniffer.recvfrom(65565)[0]
        ip_header = IP(raw_buffer[0:20])
        print(f"Protocol: {ip_header.protocol} {ip_header.src_address} -> {ip_header.dst_address}")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\n[*] Closing.")            
    if os.name == "nt":        
        sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
except Exception as err:
    print(f"\n[*] {err}")    
    if os.name == "nt":
        sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

Answer (score 0):

i assume you are running this in linux from the kali-linux tag.

however, you only place the adapter in promiscuous mode for windows.

for unix you MUST be root to set promiscuous mode,
use os.system("ifconfig eth0 promisc") as root.

Comment: I inserted an else statement under the if to (where I set the promiscuous mode) but it doesnt works..if os.name == "nt":
    sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
else:
    os.system("ifconfig eth0 promisc")

Comment: are you running as root? if not, try "sudo ifconfig eth0 promisc"

Comment: also, this may help you diagnose.  https://goyalankit.com/blog/promiscuous-mode-detection#:~:text=For%20a%20given%20interface%2C%20check,device%20is%20in%20promiscuous%20mode.

Comment: rereading your post, i see its the WLAN Adapter, and i gave you eth0, which is the lan. try wlan0.    ifconfig wlan0 promisc